# Android pager hides Tab layout if it's positioned on top of it

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I know this seems like a repeated questions but I don't understand why I can't position Tablayout on top of my ViewPager.

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp">


            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tl_ads"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                app:tabMaxWidth="16dp"
                app:tabPadding="2dp"/>


            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/vp_ads"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                android:translationZ="2dp"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop"/>





        </RelativeLayout>
```

Tablayout works just fine if I replace the RelativeLayout with Linearlayout except that's not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

> Try below may help you.
>   Error here : android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>   [image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tl_ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#9ad195"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vp_ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tl_ads"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:translationZ="2dp"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I wan't. I need the TabLayout to show on top of the viewpager. 
I tried FrameLayout and it didn't work too.

Comment: The Viewpager covers the TabLayout in this case.

Comment: after adding this line:  android:layout_below="@+id/tl_ads" in viewPager it shows below tablayout

Comment: I don't need it to show below of it. I need it to show on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"> 

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vp_ads"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:translationZ="2dp"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tl_ads"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabMaxWidth="16dp"
        app:tabPadding="2dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In a RelativeLayout, the widgets are added one on top of the other in the order in which they were declared. You had declared your tab layouts first and then declared the ViewPager. As a result of this, your tabs were being created but were being hidden by the ViewPager which occupied the entire RelativeLayout.